# Delete old data in DB Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database

I am writing small app with DB and i will on opening the app to remove all rows in DB that are older than 7 days. My DB column TIMEIN is text not date field in DB!

Here is my code in DBadapter..

```
public boolean deleteOLDdbItems(String date_row) {
    String where = KEY_TIMEIN + "<\"" + date_row + "23:59:59\"";
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;

}
```

And here is code in activity wrom where i call deleting old data on startup this activity...

```
private void removeOLDdbItems(){
    calendar_anmelden_db = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentDay = calendar_anmelden_db.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    calendar_anmelden_db.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay - 7);
    dateformat_anmelden_db= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    formattedDate_anmelden_db = dateformat_anmelden_db.format(calendar_anmelden_db.getTime());
    myDb.deleteOLDdbItems(formattedDate_anmelden_db);
}
```

On android emulator this code works perfect but on real device the code removes all rows in DB, the question is Why?

Thanks...

Comment: Maybe because strings are ordered lexically? So 01.10.2016 is smaller than 30.09.2016

Comment: hmmm i have other query with this clausule and he is working perfect???


String where = KEY_TIMEIN + " BETWEEN " + "\"" + date  + " 00:00:00" + "\""+" and " +  "\"" + date + " 23:59:59"+ "\""  ;

Comment: This is rather by chance than by design. The two conditions will not be both fulfilled if the date is not exactly the same as in the WHERE clause, no matter how dates are compared. Testing if 01.10.2016 is between 30.09.2016 00:00:00 and 30.09.2016 23:59:59 gives false because the first condition is false (it is smaller than the first date).

Comment: i dont understant good but i will change the parameter in db that column timein is date and not text? will this lose my problem? or? thanks

Comment: Reading the documentation may help. See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html section 2.2 and https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: i have changed this to date but on android emulator it work perfect and on real device it remowe all rows from the db -.-

Comment: You didn't read the doc, did you?

Comment: yes i have read it but i really dont know what to do... sry bro